# Static UITableView in Storyboard, with programmatic segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a storyboard that has a UITableViewController.  The table view has static cells, and I've configured the cells to transition to other view controllers when tapped (by control-dragging them to set up segues).  This works great.

Now I've added a row to the table, and for this row I need to transition to a UIViewController that's implemented in a different storyboard. I need to handle this one in code.

Is there a way to handle the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: for this one row in code, while letting the storyboard handle the rest of the rows which already have transitions defined?

I tried calling super within the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to invoke the "default" behaviour, but that doesn't work (undefined selector on UIViewController).  I want to invoke the storyboard's behaviour for all the rows except the one I want to handle programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. Implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and put in an if statement that executes the code you need to go to the other storyboard controller only for the row that you just added (and do nothing for any other row).

Comment: My model for how this worked was that something was replacing didSelectRowAtIndexPath and I needed to call that version to get the storyboard behaviour when in fact you get the storyboard behaviour in addition to whatever you do in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  Thanks.